# Recognising swipe gesture in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to recognise swipe gestures in a UIScrollView, I've added the scroll view using the code below, and added the swipe gestures in my storyboard, with custom transitions, when the gestures are recognised.

.h file

```
@interface PLProfileViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
}
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 875)];
}
```

The scroll view itself works fine, but since adding it none of the gesture recognisers that were working before work anymore.
Do you know how I can fix this?

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Add the `UIGestureRecognizer` to your `UIScrollView` but also implement the following method from [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```